# How to loop over the pages of API response? Laravel5

Tags: php, arrays, api, laravel-5, merge

I'm calling an API that return events (parties...etc). I'd like to call its first ten pages and have the results put together in one array.

Each response (page) includes a bunch of events.

I have this in my class: `private $events = [];`

Each time I call a new page, I want the result to be appended to this array so I can return in altogether.

```
public function events_beta($location): array {

    try {
        for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
            $response  = file_get_contents('http://api.**.com/json/events/search?app_key=**&location='.$location.'&page='.$i);
            $this->events = array_merge($this->events, json_decode($response)->events->event);
        }
    } catch ( Exceptions $e ) {
        dd($e);
        throw new Exception( 'SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
    return (array) $this->events;
}
```

My problem is that the same set of events, maybe from the first page or the last page, get repeated over and over like this:

```
[event_1, event_2, event_3, event_1, event_2, event_3, event_1, event_2, event_3]
```

Comment: Are you certain the API supports `page=x`? Have you dumped the response obtained by `file_get_contents` to see what it contains each time?

Comment: I doubled checked API docs, and its page_number=x not page=x.It works now. Thank you.